# Posting to friend's wall using Facebook API (Python)

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post to friend's wall on my behalf, using the following code:

```
import facebook

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(TOKEN)
graph.put_object("/1000000000007/feed", "feed",{'message':'TEST'}") # Where `1000000000007` is a correct user id
```

The code above doesn't work - I've tried different syntaxes but it seems that I cannot get it right.

I have no problem posting on my own wall, I also have `publish_stream` permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible (anymore) to post to the wall of a friend, no serious App would do this anyway.

Also, `publish_stream` is deprecated, you should use `publish_actions` if you want to post on the wall of the authorized user.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it (e.g. by simulating logging on Facebook)?

Comment: who would you want to log in? not to mention that this would be illegal.

Comment: Why would logging in on my account be illegal?

Comment: "simulating logging on Facebook" - that is surely illegal :) - and i am not sure what the point would be, you could still not post on the wall of a friend. that´s just not going to happen, facebook does not allow it for a very good reason.